# Firebase downloadURLWithCompletion error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a video from my firebase storage. The way I am doing that is by using the `.downloadURLWithCompletion` function. When ever the function executes, I receive this error

```
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object videos/video1.m4v
    
 does not exist." UserInfo={object=videos/video1.m4v
    
, bucket=**********.appspot.com, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}, data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 20202022 636f6465 223a2034 30342c0a 20202020 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 4e6f7420 466f756e 64220a20 207d0a7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Object videos/video1.m4v
    
 does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}
```

I have changed my storage settings on firebase to allow unauthenticated access:[image]

I have also checked to make sure that the storage link is correct:[image]

Here is the code that is accessing the Firebase storage:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseStorage

class VideoViewController: UIViewController
{
    var videoUrl:NSURL!
    var storageRef:FIRStorageReference!
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://**********.appspot.com")
        let videosRef = storageRef.child("videos")
        let videoName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("videoName") as! String
            
        videosRef.child(videoName).downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error!)
            }
            else
            {
                self.videoUrl = URL
                
                do
                {
                    try self.playVideo()
                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error")
                }

            }
        }
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

So, I tried using a direct link and it worked!

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        storageRef = "gs://*************.appspot.com"
        let videosRef = "videos"
        let videoName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("videoName") as! String
        
        storage.referenceForURL("\(storageRef)/\(videosRef)/\(videoName)").downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error!)
            }
            else
            {
                self.videoUrl = URL
                
                do
                {
                    try self.playVideo()
                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error")
                }

            }
        }
```

Of course, using a direct link for something like this isn't exactly the best way to get data. So next I compared the two links generated by printing them out. Here is how I printed the first link:

```
var videoUrl:NSURL!
var storageRef:FIRStorageReference!
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://*********.appspot.com")
        let videosRef = storageRef.child("videos")
        let videoName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("videoName") as! String
        print(videosRef.child(videoName))
```

and it printed

`gs://***********.appspot.com/videos/video1.m4v`

And the second link:

```
var videoUrl:NSURL!
var storageRef:String!
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        storageRef = "gs://***********.appspot.com"
        let videosRef = "videos"
        let videoName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("videoName") as! String
        print("\(storageRef)/\(videosRef)/\(videoName)")
```

What it printed

`gs://***********.appspot.com/videos/video1.m4v`

Now, I also tried printing the value of `videoName` to make sure that it was correct and every time that I printed it out it was `video1.m4v`

I banked out the link to my firebase storage, but I can assure you that the link is correct all around.

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error? To me everything looks to be in place.

Thanks!

Comment: Everything looks correct to me as well--which is why I'm puzzled. 404 means that the object isn't found, which means that the bucket is wrong (since it's blanked out, I can't see if they match, but I assume they do), or the file is somehow named incorrectly. I've occasionally seen issues where characters are rendered the same, but are actually different unicode points (the period maybe), which would cause them to be "different files" and thus not exist. Can you repeat this issue with another file?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Ive tried downloading it using a different file and it has the same result; however, I found that if I were to do the direct link using the storage.referenceForURL("\(storageRef)/\(videosRef)/\(videoName)") function (along with making some other changes like changing all of those variables into strings) then it works, so the problem must have to do with how I'm creating the link. The only thing wrong with that is when I print the value of videosRef.child(videoName) its the exact same as the direct like I showed earlier.

Comment: could you try `let videosRef2 = videosRef.child(videoName)` and then use `videosRef2.downloadURLWithCompletion` instead. I know it sounds stupid but this case already seems pretty bizarre

Comment: @Chris I tried it but it gives me the exact same error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -- if there is an issue with the underlying representation of a ref this may help:

instead of:

```
    videosRef.child(videoName).downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
```

do:

```
    storage.referenceForURL(String(videosRef.child(videoName))).downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
```

that is, does referenceForURL of the stringValue do something different than a direct call.  It shouldn't -- if it does, it might have something to do with your videoName.  Maybe it ends with a slash?  Can you post the value of your videoName?

Comment: Ok, so I tried doing what you suggested and it worked surprisingly (after translating videosRef.child(videoName) into a string). That is closer, but still not what I'm looking for. I printed out the value of video name and it is video1.m4v. Still looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to download the image without passing the full URL path?

If so, I think `downloadURLWithCompletion` requires the full URL path.

I can't test this, since I don't have my data set up this way (I just store the full URLs to media files in firebase storage to my firebase database), but try this:

```
videosRef.child(videoName).dataWithMaxSize(INT64_MAX, completion: { (data, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error downloading: \(error)")
        return
    }
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this wont work. Not only am I **not** trying to download a image (it's a video that I'm trying to download) but also I have a system already in place to play video from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

In your firebase storage, you haven't placed your video file inside a folder called videos.

And despite this you try to access to .../**videos**/filename which doesn't exist. Either try to remove the /videos from: gs://***********.appspot.com **/videos** /video1.m4v

or

Either create a folder called videos inside your firebase storage and then add the same video inside it with the same name (since you cant drag and drop files into other folders), or remove the:
let videosRef = "videos"
from your path.

Hope it helps.